# How do I echo username, full name, and login time from finger into columns? I'm using bash on openSUSE13.1

Tags: bash, awk, opensuse

Basically I have three users logged in to my machine right now. Test User1, Test User2, and Test User3.

I would like to use finger to get username, full name and the time they logged into the machine.

I would like to output the information like so:

```
Login        Name            Login Time

testuser1    Test User1      1300

testuser2    Test User2      1600

testuser3    Tesr User3      1930
```

I have two tabs in between Login and Name and three tabs between Login Time. The same goes for the user information below each header.

I cannot figure out how to pull this data from finger very well and I absolutely cannot figure out how to get the information into nice, neat, readable columns. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be perfect so you'll have to play around with `substr` starting and ending points. Should be good enough to get you started:

```
finger -s testuser1 testuser2 testuser3 | awk '{print substr($0,1,31),substr($0,46,14)}'
```

Comment: Super close, I know nothing about substr and only a little about awk. Very close though! Thank you, I think I can get where I need with that!

Comment: Thank you for the edit by the way. I really wish I knew how you made that look. I feel like I'll be here a lot as a n00b to all this and I can tell how formatting and such is very helpful to all you knowledgeable wizards of scripting! Thanks again!

Comment: @user3347022 You're welcome. [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is a good write up on `awk` string functions. You can toggle with `substr` to get the output you desire. Good Luck! `:)`

Comment: @user3347022 [This](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) should help you with the formatting here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ jaypal Last question, in finger -s it give me three iteration of my login. The console login, my user login, and my terminal box. I've been trying to use uniq to get only my user login information from finger -s. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3347022 You can use `!a[$1]++` to filter out the dups. Something like `finger -s ... | awk '!a[$1]++{print substr($0,1,31),substr($0,46,14)}'`

Comment: @ jaypal Pure gold! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Try `:r!finger`.  On my Mac, I get nice columns.  YMMV.

```
:help :r!
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned I'm on openSUSE13.1, I tried >r!finger with no luck, thank you though!

Comment: Originally, this question was tagged with "vim" and I was giving you the way to read the output of `finger` into the current buffer.  Hence the leading `:`.

Comment: Oh cool cool, I'm super new. Sorry for my confusion and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `awk`:

```
finger -l | awk '{ split($1, a, OFS); print a[2], a[4], substr($3, 20, 6) }' FS="\n" RS= | column -t
```

The `-l` flag of `finger` produces a multi-line format (and is compatible with the `-s` flag). This is useful when fields like 'name' are absent. We can then process the records using `awk` in paragraph mode. In my example above, you can adjust the sub-string to suit the datespec of your choice. If you have `gawk`, then you'll have access to some [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) that may interest you if you wish to change the spec. Finally, you can print the fields of interest into `column -t` for pretty printing. HTH.